# How to disable input on react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

How to disable input on `react-select`? Is that possible? I just want it to be a dropdown.

```
<Select
    placeholder="Action"
    className="col-3 mt-3"
    value={orderStatusInput}
    onChange={this.onOrderStatusChange}
    options={orderStatusOptions}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Title and description was misleading, I thought you wanted to disable the input. @AlexMcKay has correct answer.

Comment: @DrewReese way to misread the question and put it on OP

Comment: @AlexMckay "How to disable input on react-select?" isn't exactly an ambiguous question, and why would one assume a select component *wasn't* already a dropdown. ‍♂️

Comment: '"How to disable input on react-select?" isn't exactly an ambiguous question' - so we agree then :) I think the fact that OP didn't say "Disable react-select", said he "just want(ed) it to be a dropdown" and also provided a screenshot with a cursor made it quite clear. I am not looking to attack you I just thought of all poorly asked questions on SO it was unfair to call out OP.

Answer (score 38):

To make React Select act as a dropdown

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactSelect isSearchable={false} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want the search input to be disabled and just want it to be a dropdown, you can set the `isSearchable` property to `false`:

```
<Select
  placeholder="Action"
  className="col-3 mt-3"
  value={orderStatusInput}
  onChange={this.onOrderStatusChange}
  options={orderStatusOptions}
  isSearchable={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<Select isDisabled={true} />`